# Navigating from a BasicPage to a BasicPage in c# metro application

Tags: c#, navigation

Hi I am working on a metro app as a school assignment but I am having problems navigating from a basicPage to another basicPage.

I keep getting a `Value cannot be null` error. This is my Code in the button: `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage1), null);`.

Can anyone help me? immediate response would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass a navigation argument, use the following.

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage1));
```